# Date and shift time type filter in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using SQL Server 2016 and I have a sensor table as follow:

| SensorCode | SensorStatus | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PS01A | Active | 2019-11-20 01:38:11.850 |
| PS01B | Active | 2019-11-20 02:30:09.850 |
| PS01C | Active | 2019-11-20 05:32:11.004 |
| PS01D | Active | 2019-11-20 07:38:07.997 |
| PS01E | Active | 2019-11-20 11:38:06.700 |

How can I filter above table with date and shift type as input parameter in stored procedure? I can make the query for filter the date but not the shift type.

For the shift type use below table as reference:

| ShiftType | StartTime | EndTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Day | 06:00:00 | 17:59:59 |
| Night | 18:00:00 | 05:59:59 |

and here is my code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_SENSOR_STATE]
@date DATE,
@shifttypeid INT,
@shifttype NVARCHAR(MAX)

AS

BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF (@shifttype = 'DAY')
SET @shifttypeid = 0
ELSE
SET @shifttypeid = 1
    
SELECT [SensorCode]
      ,[SensorStatus]
      ,[Timestamp]

FROM [MyTable].[dbo].[SensorState] SS

WHERE
--@date = CAST(SS.Timestamp AS DATE)
CASE @shifttypeid
WHEN 0 THEN @date = CAST(SS.Timestamp AS DATE) AND DATEPART(HH, SS.Timestamp) BETWEEN 6 AND 18
WHEN 1 THEN @date = CAST(SS.Timestamp AS DATE) AND DATEPART(HH, SS.Timestamp) BETWEEN 18 AND 6
END

END
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?  MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Microsoft SQL Server, etc, etc?  And what are the exact data types of all the columns?  Particularly the StartTime and EndTime columns.

Comment: Sorry for less information. I just updated now. For shift type table, I don't have it in my DB so I make a table for better explanation. Maybe the datatype is TIME or you have better idea?

Comment: I updated the code above but I get stuck so I don't provide the result. Right now I get incorrect syntax error near '='.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `BETWEEN 18 AND 6` it will never be true. Also for `BETWEEN`, the checking condition is inclusive `BETWEEN 6 AND 18` will means `>= 6 AND <= 18` which is not exactly what you want. It is best to use `>=` and `<`

```
WHERE (
          CAST(SS.Timestamp AS DATE) = @date
      OR  (    
               @shifttypeid = 1 
           AND CAST(SS.Timestamp AS DATE) = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @date)
          )
      )
AND   (
          (    -- Day Shift
               @shifttypeid = 0
          AND  DATEPART(HH, SS.Timestamp) >= 6
          AND  DATEPART(HH, SS.Timestamp) < 18
          )
      OR  (    -- Night Shift
               @shifttypeid = 1
          AND  (
                   DATEPART(HH, SS.Timestamp) < 6
               OR  DATEPART(HH, SS.Timestamp) >= 18
               )
          )
      )
```

Added condition to handle `Night Shift` Date

---

EDIT : based on `@shifttypeid` filter the required `Timestamp` accordingly.

```
WHERE  (    -- Day Shift 06:00 to 18:00
            @shifttypeid = 0
       AND  SS.Timestamp >= DATEADD(HOUR,  6, CAST(@date AS DATETIME))
       AND  SS.Timestamp <  DATEADD(HOUR, 18, CAST(@date AS DATETIME))
       )   
OR     (    -- Night Shfit 18:00 to 06:00
            @shifttypeid = 1
       AND  SS.Timestamp >= DATEADD(HOUR, 18, CAST(@date AS DATETIME))
       AND  SS.Timestamp <  DATEADD(HOUR, 30, CAST(@date AS DATETIME))
       )
```

Comment: your code is working good but the result for night shift should be + 1 day. Do you how to work with that?

Comment: Your latest code is almost perfect but when I fill the date by e.g. 2021-04-27 and fill shifttype by night, I get the data from 2021-04-27 00:00 until 06:00 and 18:00 until 23:59 and 2021-04-28 from 00:00 until 06:00. How do I exclude the 00:00 until 06:00 on 2021-04-27? I really appreciate your effort